# Lightweight and simple alternatives to wordpress for usermanagement?

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I have made a front end of my website using [`Framework7`](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/). I need to integrate the user login/seesion and minimal data to the frontend.

I can integrate wordpress, but `wordpress` seems to be an overkill as all I want to do is allow users to login and maintain and update very simple data (test scores) in the server.

Is there any alternative to `wordpress`, which is reasonably secure and can maintain user database and login sessions.

I understand that this is not a programming question, but I could not find any other forum in stackexchange which was more suitable than stackoverflow.

Thanks

Comment: you can just make a login form & database connection with php without a framework. Which is the simple solution. Or use a mvc framework like Laravel

Comment: Actually, there is now https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, which might be a good place to ask this type of question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Answer my own question, my shortlist:
Only for login,profile etc and no xtra stuff:
1, [Userfrosting](http://www.userfrosting.com/) (Planning to use this one)
2, [Huge](https://github.com/panique/huge)
3, [Hybridauth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#index)

Bigger frameworks having more than simple login:
1,[Laravel](http://laravel.com/)
2, [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/)
3, [Sympfony](http://symfony.com)

Comment: If you like Laravel, it's worth mentioning that UserFrosting uses the Eloquent ORM (which is a Laravel component).  Full disclosure - I am the author of UserFrosting ;-)